# Effect of mat2gray on multithresh

Tags: matlab, image-processing, cluster-analysis, image-segmentation

I do not get why a segmentation obtained by using `multithresh` on an "original" double image is different from a segmentation using the same parameters on the same image scaled by `mat2gray`.

E.g.:

```
testimage = randi(100,[200 200]);
figure;imagesc(testimage)


threshs = multithresh(testimage,5);
l0 = imquantize(testimage,threshs);

threshs = multithresh(mat2gray(testimage),5);
l1 = imquantize(mat2gray(testimage),threshs);
```

Here, in my case `l1` is different from `l0` in 808 pixels. Why? The relative differences between pixels in `testimage` and `mat2gray(testimage)` should be equivalent, just the absolute differences change. How is this important to multithresh?

Comment: My guess is that an image with range `0-max(img)>1`  is treated as a `0-255` image, and that has an influence in multitresh

Comment: @AnderBiguri: what exactly would that mean? What happens to value > 255? The behaviour is present also when testimage is double, btw. Also note that it appears to me that testimage is scaled to [0 1] when it is of type float (see line 224 of multithresh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indirectly running into a floating precision error. If we modify a little your code, just to visualize it

```
testimage = randi(100,[200 200]);
figure;imagesc(testimage)

gray_image=mat2gray(testimage);

threshs1 = multithresh(testimage,5);
l0 = imquantize(testimage,threshs1);

threshs2 = multithresh(gray_image,5);
l1 = imquantize(gray_image,threshs2);

%For this example
threshs1
%threshs1 =
%       17.6941    34.0000    50.6941    67.0000    83.6941

threshs2
%threshs2 =
%        0.1686     0.3333     0.5020     0.6667     0.8353
```

Then we find one of the discrepant points in both original matrices

```
find(l0~=l1,1)
%ans =
%    67

testimage(67)
%ans =
%    34

gray_image(67)
%ans =
%    0.3333
```

And Here is where the floating precision comes into play

```
testimage(67)==threshs1(2)  % 34 == 34.0000
%ans =
%     1

gray_image(67)==threshs2(2) % 0.3333 == 0.3333
%ans =
%     0
```

The value of `1/3` is not properly saved into binary, [see here for an explanation why](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/57444-faq-why-is-0-3-0-2-0-1-not-equal-to-zero), `imquantize` must be comparing the values of the image to the thresholds with a `>=` or similar, and it would pass in one case and fail in the other.

Sadly I cannot see a simple way to modify your code to make sure `l0` and `l1` are equal in every case.

Comment: interesting, thanks for the answer! Now I am wondering why thresh2 is not  thresh1 ./ 100 in the first place...

Comment: I'm guessing that has to do with the mapping of `mat2gray` from `testimage` to `gray_image`. `gray_image` is not `testimage./100` either, so I don't see how thresholds would be

Comment: yes, true, because the smallest value in testimage usually will be 1 (and not 0!). Therefore, threshs2 = (threshs1-1) / (100-1).